# NEST ElasticSearch: Min value is always 0

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm relatively new to ElasticSearch and NEST. In a project, I'm using ElasticSearch 2.2.0 & ElasticSearch.Net 1.7.2 with NEST.

I couldn't get the min aggregation to work. It returns 0 always.

Here is my code to get the aggregation values:

```
const string priceAggNameMin = "price_aggregation_min";
const string priceAggNameMax = "price_aggregation_max";

var searchResponse = _esClient.Search<ProductGroupDto>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Min(priceAggNameMin, st => st
            .Field(o => o.Price))
        .Max(priceAggNameMax, st => st
            .Field(o => o.Price))));

LogElasticSearchRequest(searchResponse.RequestInformation.RequestUrl);

var minPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(searchResponse.Aggs.Min(priceAggNameMin).Value);
var maxPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(searchResponse.Aggs.Max(priceAggNameMax).Value);
```

The raw request to ES (generated by NEST) looks like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "price_aggregation_min": {
            "min": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        },
        "price_aggregation_max": {
            "max": {
                "field": "price"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the response from Postman for this query looks like this:

```
{
    ....
    "aggregations": {
        "price_aggregation_max": {
          "value": 51.9
        },
        "price_aggregation_min": {
          "value": 12
        }
    }
}
```

So, it appears that ES responds the correct value for min aggregation, but NEST returns that as 0.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: the max aggregation works fine, any ways

Comment: NEST 1.7.2 is not compatible with ES 2.x maybe this is the issue here.

Comment: Makes sense. Will give it a go. And that means I have to upgrade my codebase too as the APIs have changed a lot between these versions. Will update once I have upgraded. Thanks Rob.

Comment: No luck. Have upgraded ElasticSearch.Net and NEST to the latest 2.0.5. Still returns 0.

Comment: May you share index mapping?

Comment: Thanks for the time, @Rob. Fresh mind in the morning, I just found that I was querying the wrong index. Silly me. Added `...s => s.Index(indexName).Aggregations(...` and it is fine now.